# SQL Job Status

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am actually working on SP in SQL 2005. Using SP i am creating a job and am scheduling it for a particular time. These jobs take atleast 5 to 10 min to complete as the database is very huge. But I am not aware of how to check the status of the Job. I want to know if it has got completed successfully or was there any error in execution. On exception i also return proper error code. But i am not aware of where i can check for this error code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I could find, maybe it solves your problem:

1. SP to get the current job activiity.

> ```
>  exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobactivity  @job_id = (your job_id here)
> ```

You can execute this SP and place the result in a temp table and get the required result from there.

Otherwise have a look at these tables:

- msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity
- msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory

Run the following to see the association between these tables.

> exec sp_helptext sp_help_jobactivity

Answer (score 0):

--Copy in Query analizer and format it properly so you can understand it easyly
--To execute your task(Job) using Query
exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='Job Name',@server_name = server name
-- After executing query to check weateher it finished or not
Declare @JobId as varchar(36)
Select @JobId = job_id from sysjobs where name = 'Your Job Name'
Declare @JobStatus as int set @JobStatus = -1
While @JobStatus <= -1
Begin
        --Provide TimeDelay according your Job
    select @JobStatus = isnull(run_status ,-1)
    from sysjobactivity JA,sysjobhistory JH
    where JA.job_history_id = JH.instance_id and JA.job_id = @JobId
End
select @JobStatus

null = Running
1 = Fininshed successfully
0 = Finished with error

--Once your Job will fininsh you'll get result

Answer (score 0):

I got a better code from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30916/)

```
Use msdb
go

select distinct j.Name as "Job Name", j.description as "Job Description", h.run_date as LastStatusDate, 
case h.run_status 
when 0 then 'Failed' 
when 1 then 'Successful' 
when 3 then 'Cancelled' 
--when 4 then 'In Progress' 
end as JobStatus
from sysJobHistory h, sysJobs j
where j.job_id = h.job_id and h.run_date = 
(select max(hi.run_date) from sysJobHistory hi where h.job_id = hi.job_id)
order by 1
```

Comment: WARNING: run_status of 4 (In Progress) does not occur (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx)